# How to get and set a pixel's color in the CMYK format?

Tags: c#, image-processing, rgb, cmyk

Can I set a pixel's color in a Bitmap image using the CMYK format? Or must I convert the color to RGB values?

Comment: Yes, you can. After converting.

Comment: So I must Convert to RGB first then set color ?

Comment: Yes. Or choose another image format which allow to store data in CMYK.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert first. Just incase you were wondering how it was done:

The R,G,B values are given in the range of 0..255.
The red (R) color is calculated from the cyan (C) and black (K) colors:

```
 R = 255 × (1-C) × (1-K)
```

The green color (G) is calculated from the magenta (M) and black (K) colors:

```
 G = 255 × (1-M) × (1-K)
```

The blue color (B) is calculated from the yellow (Y) and black (K) colors:

```
 B = 255 × (1-Y) × (1-K)
```

Comment: By using this formula you lose the CMYK tone. Ex: Think about a CMYK color like (0,100,100,0). If you convert it to RGB, green and blue channels will be always negative (zero). And in the end, the original CMYK color will be only a red on the RGB scale.